# how to make a collapsible search box to cover navbar items on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to put a search box on the right-hand side of my bootstrap `navbar`, and I want to make it expand and cover all the items in the navbar except the `navbar-brand` once the user clicks on it.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
<div class="d-flex pt-3  mb-1 pb-0 align-self-end" style="background-color: transparent;" >

  <div class="container-search">
    <form class="searchbar" action="{% url 'search' %}"> 
      <input type="search" placeholder="Search" name="search" class="searchbar-input" value="{{ values.keywords}}" onkeyup="buttonUp();" required> 
      <input type="submit" class="searchbar-submit" value="GO"> 
      <span class="searchbar-icon"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> 
    </form>
  </div>


</div>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
   .container-search {
     max-width: 600px;
    }

    .searchbar {
        position: relative;
        min-width: 50px;
        width: 0%;
        height: 50px;
        float: right;
        overflow: hidden;
        -webkit-transition: width 0.3s;
        -moz-transition: width 0.3s;
        -ms-transition: width 0.3s;
        -o-transition: width 0.3s;
        transition: width 0.3s
    }

    .searchbar-input {
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        border: 0;
        outline: 0;
        background: #c5c5c5;
        width: 80vw;
        height: 50px;
        margin: 0;
        /* padding: 0px 55px 0px 20px; */
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #fff;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .searchbar-input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        color: #fff
    }

    .searchbar-input:-moz-placeholder {
        color: #fff
    }

    .searchbar-input::-moz-placeholder {
        color: #fff
    }

    .searchbar-input:-ms-input-placeholder {
        color: #fff
    }

    .searchbar-icon,
    .searchbar-submit {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        font-family: verdana;
        font-size: 22px;
        right: 0;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        border: 0;
        outline: 0;
        line-height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #fff;
        background: #c2c2c2;
        border-left: 1px solid white
    }

    .searchbar-open {
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

JS:

```
<script>  
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var submitIcon = $('.searchbar-icon');
    var inputBox = $('.searchbar-input');
    var searchbar = $('.searchbar');
    var isOpen = false;
    submitIcon.click(function(){
      if(isOpen == false){
      searchbar.addClass('searchbar-open');
      inputBox.focus();
      isOpen = true;
      } else {
      searchbar.removeClass('searchbar-open');
      inputBox.focusout();
      isOpen = false;
      }
    });
    submitIcon.mouseup(function(){
      return false;
    });
    searchbar.mouseup(function(){
      return false;
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function(){
      if(isOpen == true){
        $('.searchbar-icon').css('display','block');
        submitIcon.click();
      }
    });
  });

  function buttonUp(){
    var inputVal = $('.searchbar-input').val();
    inputVal = $.trim(inputVal).length;
    if( inputVal !== 0){
      $('.searchbar-icon').css('display','none');
    } else {
      $('.searchbar-input').val('');
      $('.searchbar-icon').css('display','block');
    }
  }

</script>
```

For example, I want to make something like the one in the [bosch](https://www.bosch.com/) website.

The problem with my code is that after expansion, the input box expands towards the right and goes out of screen. Instead, I want it to expand inside the navbar, and cover the menu items.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping things simple. So, below is simple code using only CSS and bootstrap.

```css
.navbar-nav{
  position: relative;
}


.search:focus{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
  <!-- Links -->
  <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1 justify-content-end">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <input class="search" type="text" placeholder="Search"/>
    </li>
  </ul>

</nav>
```

Comment: the problem is that I don't want the search box to be a part of `navbar-nav` list. I aligned the menu items on the left-hand side, and put some icons on the right-hand side of the navbar. I want to put the search box under icons which is out of `<ul class="navbar-nav....`